# Is there a BOOTP query tool that exists for macOS?

Tags: macos, command-line

I would like to query a BOOTP server as a specific MAC address to test the response. What tools exists for macOS?
Something like this? https://www.weird-solutions.com/enterprise-solutions/bootp-turbo

Comment: What tool or package would you use on another os? Adding that might help narrow your options. I could see a [fairly short python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25124500/sending-dhcp-discover-using-python-scapy) / C program filling the shoes, but if you have a code base / candidate in mind, it might be a simple research task to find it on macOS.

Comment: @bmike One that will simulate a bootp query as if it were a device looking to boot.

Comment: The code I linked to in my comment above does exactly what you want - so fire up python and see if the libraries needed are portable to macos. Also, just virtualization Linux on Mac isn’t a bad solution if you have something you know you like and no one here knows a similar recommendation.

Comment: @bmike Thanks, I will look that python script over.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to see if a BOOTP machine responds to a particular MAC address, just use a virtuall machine with a manually configured MAC address

In VirtualBox:

[image]

Comment: Where do I see the results of the bootp query? @Allan Like this: https://www.weird-solutions.com/enterprise-solutions/bootp-turbo

Comment: @FrankBarcenas You’d need wireshark or another packet capture tool to use the GUI to do this.

Comment: Allan - you can even just use macOS to define a second network device on the Mac and spoof the hardware without needing any third party software.

Comment: As @bmike stated, you would need a sniffer like Wireshark.  I suggested a VM with a spoofed MAC because BOOTP was normally used with diskless workstations and having this setup would allow you to simulate the whole boot process.

Answer (score 0):

[You can spoof your MAC address](http://osxdaily.com/2012/03/01/change-mac-address-os-x/), which is significantly less effort than setting up a VM.

Your command should be along the lines `sudo ifconfig en1 Wi-Fi xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx`, where `en1` is your network interface and `xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx` is the MAC address you'd like to spoof as.

Comment: It is considerably less effort, but how does a spoof survive when the OS ***isn't*** loaded?

Comment: @Allan Does it not persist through a restart?

Comment: `ifconfig` operates at the OS level, not the physical layer so it wouldn't be in effect when the OS isn't loaded like in the pre-boot stage.